# PHP - Create new array from data and sum data in duplicate keys

Tags: php, arrays, data-manipulation

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uniqid] => 123
            [typeid] => 100
            [value] => 5000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uniqid] => 234
            [typeid] => 101
            [value] => 1000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [uniqid] => 234
            [typeid] => 101
            [value] => 1000
        )


    [3] => Array
        (
            [uniqid] => 234
            [typeid] => 100
            [value] => 7000
        )
)
```

I need to create another array with the values of **'uniqid'** as indexes and the values of **'typeid'** as keys.

I also need to check whether **'typeid'** is a duplicate under that specific **'uniqid'** and if so sum the value.

Example of what the new array would roughly look like given the example dataset:

```
Array
(
    [123] => Array
        (
            [100] => 5000
        )

    [234] => Array
        (
            [100] => 7000
            [101] => 2000
        )
)
```

I understand how to loop through the first array and map the second but not sure how to check for duplication and sum the values within the same **'uniqid'**.

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: "_I understand how to loop through the first array and map the second but not sure how to check for duplication and sum the values_" Okay, so _do that_ then ask _about that_. You are basically saying you know how to do half of your question but still want one of us to do it for you?

Comment: Please do the bit you know how do, and then at least attempt the bit you're unsure about. Then, if you're still stuck, ask us about the specific problem you've found, and show us the code you've already got. Basically, your question here is premature, because you don't yet have problem (you just think you might have one, later on).

Comment: You can test for existence of keys in your associative array using [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php). Maybe with that function you can figure out how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The below answer gives the expected result. To get result in required order will require some more conditions. I think it would be helpful.

```
$input=[
    ['uniqid'=>123,'typeid'=>100,'value'=>5000],
    ['uniqid'=>234,'typeid'=>101,'value'=>1000],
    ['uniqid'=>234,'typeid'=>101,'value'=>1000],
    ['uniqid'=>234,'typeid'=>100,'value'=>7000]
];
$output =[];
foreach($input  as $elm){
    $output[$elm['uniqid']] [$elm['typeid']]+=$elm['value'];
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($output);
```